# Returning records inserted by plpgsql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, sql-insert

I have a cron job that executes a plpgsql function in postgres.  This function inserts zero to many records into table.  What's the best way to also return the records that have been created by the function as it's result?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luckily that can be done rather easily. Say, you are inserting into table `insert_tbl` ...

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_ins_return()
  RETURNS SETOF insert_tbl AS
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
INSERT INTO insert_tbl
SELECT * FROM othertable LIMIT 3 -- or where ever your rows come from ...
RETURNING *;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```sql
SELECT * FROM f_ins_return();
```

Key elements:

[`RETURNS SETOF insert_tbl`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html)
[`RETURN QUERY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)
[`RETURNING *`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a column in which you put a value. That value is one of a small set of restricted values. The values are in this case the source of the way how the record is created. One value is cron job, the other one human insertion or other ways to create a record in that table. Afterwards can you find out which record is created when by which means using an SQL.